# fedora strongswan resolvconf: Interface can't be the loopback interface

Tags: strongswan, resolvconf

I am getting this error when trying to use `sudo strongswan up CONNECTION_NAME` on Fedora 29

```
installing DNS server ###.##.#.## via resolvconf
resolvconf: Interface can't be the loopback interface (lo). Sorry.
removing DNS server ###.##.#.## via resolvconf
resolvconf: Interface can't be the loopback interface (lo). Sorry.
adding DNS server failed
```

There is no documentation anywhere on the internet when i google search this exact error or similar error messages.

I am suspecting there is something wrong with `resolvconf` but i am unsure how to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like newer (or different) versions of `resolvconf` have problems with the interface prefix that strongSwan's *resolve* plugin uses to install DNS servers via `resolvconf`.

The default value is `lo.inet.ipsec.` (to which the DNS server's IP address is added).  The prefix can be changed with the `charon.plugins.resolve.resolvconf.iface_prefix` option in [strongswan.conf](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/StrongswanConf) (or the `resolve.conf` snippet in the `strongswan.d/charon` directory). So perhaps try a different prefix/interface (make sure to consider and possibly change `/etc/resolvconf/interface-order` so the installed DNS servers have a high priority).

**Edit:** Looks like this error message is produced by some versions of the resolvconf compatibility layer of `systemd` (prior to v240, not sure if there is still an error with that and newer versions or if it's just different). So I'm not sure if `interface-order` is actually relevant (or does even exist). I guess you can just try to replace `lo` in the prefix with the physical interface and see if the DNS servers provided via IKE are actually used when the VPN is up.